# Submenu disappears on hover when above slider thumbnails

Tags: css, hover, submenu

On this site: http://fanmailz.nl.s1.rodekiwi.nl/ the submenu disappears when I hover on the last items of "Producten & Diensten". E.g. I can't click on "Het Fanmailz patienten feelgood programma"
This only happens when scrolled all the way UP and when the thumbnails of the slider appear.

I've tried changing some z-indexes but didn't work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Please provide us with your code or a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the z-index of both `.tp-bannertimer` and `.tp-bullets` to 20. This fixed the error and caused them to lie underneath the menu, as intended.